# Restrict google maps search box autocomplete to certain place types

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out a way to restrict the google maps SearchBox autocomplete to only show predictions of a certain place type, like only have it predict restaurants, for instance. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I have tried, but with no success:

```
// Get search box div element
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

var options = {
type: ['restaurant']
}

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);
```

Comment: Sadly, this isn't possible (yet).

Comment: are you sure @AndrewLi?
I've found a page that allows for filtering by city & just for hotels/lodgings. Am I missing something?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

Comment: @TinusWagner : The part you mentioned in the link is nearbySearch for a category, it doesn't entertain text search as you are trying to do.